# Bitmapfactory and Factory Design Pattern

Tags: java, android, bitmap

From my understanding the below three statements are correct:
(1) Factory design pattern is that by calling a factory class you can use it to produce different classes.
(2) Bitmapfactory follows factory design pattern.
(3) Bitmapfactory only produce bitmap classes.

However, if (1) is true than (2) + (3) cannot be true, and vice versa, so at least one of these statements must be false, but I am not sure which one... Can anyone enlighten me a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: BitmapFactory creates bitmaps.

Comment: @blackapps then why dont we just use Bitmap class to create bitmap object then? why the hassle?

Comment: I have no idea what hassle you encounter using BitmapFactory to create a bitmap from an image file.

Comment: i guess i am a purist, i would prefer using with understanding rather than just using. and apparently i am using bitmapfactory quite extensively right now or otherwise i wouldn't have asked this theoretical question...

Comment: Ok. Maybe i should not have reacted. Hope others will come and tell you.